# How to skip null bitmap value from a database when retrieving an image

Tags: vb.net, winforms, null, bitmapimage

I am trying to set a flowlayoutpanel to show images from access database VB.net, but when it reads an empty cell from the image column is gives me error saying

> specified cast is invalid

the image data is in bytes I just don't know how to properly skip a cell when there's no data. how to properly set a condition for checking null bytes?

here's my code

```
Private Sub loadData()
  cn.Open()
  cmd = New OleDbCommand("select [Image Name], [Item Name] from tbl_item_image", cn)

  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
  While dr.Read
    Dim len As Long = dr.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0)
    Dim array(CInt(len)) As Byte
    dr.GetBytes(0, 0, array, 0, CInt(len))

    pic = New PictureBox
    pic.Width = 100
    pic.Height = 100
    pic.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
           
    mybtn = New Button
    mybtn.Width = 100
    mybtn.Height = 30

    AddHandler mybtn.Click, AddressOf OnButton_Click
    AddHandler mybtn.MouseHover, AddressOf OnButton_MouseHove

    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(array)
    Dim bitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

    pic.BackgroundImage = bitmap  
    mybtn.Text = dr.Item("Item Name").ToString
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pic)
    pic.Controls.Add(mybtn)
  End While
  dr.Close()
  cn.Close()
End Sub
```

I have tried setting an If statements for checking null or empty values but I don't really know how to do it properly.

Comment: Try `If Not IsDBNull(dr("Image Name")) Then`

Comment: You probably want something like `dim imgValue = dr.GetValue(0) if imgValue = DBNull.Value then continue while` -- The returned value, if not null, can be cast (`DirectCast()`) directly to `Byte()`, which is already an array. You don't need to get the length to build another

Comment: As a note, especially with an Access db, it's quite important that you declare and dispose of the Connection object in-place. Don't try store it

Comment: OMG LarsTech! your suggestion worked like a charm thank you so much! And thank you Jimi for your suggestion as well I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Emma You can also exclude null values in the database query: `SELECT [Image Name], [Item Name] FROM tbl_item_image WHERE [Image Name] IS NOT NULL`, but then you wouldn't get the [Item Name] values that don't have an [Image Name] - although that might be what you want.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't want to exclude the null values since I still need the [Item Name] values to appear in the label and with an empty picturebox and a label. Anyway its ok now thanks to Lasrtech, they gave me exactly the code I need. Thanks for the advise, I can use that too in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
If Not Convert.IsDBNull(your image data) Then

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(your image data, Byte()))

        pic.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms))

        ms.Dispose()

    Else

        pic.Image = Nothing

    End If
```